# Reset Pagination li list when new query is executed

Tags: jquery

I have a basic jquery pagination.
The data is loaded and displays correctly.
above my results I have added a checkbox to filter these results.
this works fine but does not update the result pagination.
i.e. the first query returns 15 results.
when clicking the checkbox, the new result on returns 10 results.
my pagination still stays for all 15 results - how do I get this to update when I execute a different query?

Comment: A testpage with some code would help a lot. If you use any plugins, mention them.

Comment: Ive only used jquery-latest.js and basic '$("#contentDiv").load("pagination_general.php?page=1&function=query_nonpermanent", Hide_Load());'
calls for the nav.
the first display of the pagination comes from the first query.
I need to update this display when a new query is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is to remove the first instance of the loader and load the first paginated query with a submit button. The next submission replaces the pagination with the correct number, and so forth.